# AWS - Manage data between DynamoDB and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I have a question on how to manage/handle data properly by using DynamoDB and S3.
For example, I have a DynamoDB table that contains a list of user data(name, email, phone no. and etc). I also have the JSON file of the user data in S3.

And, how can I update the JSON file in S3, when I update the user data in DynamoDB? Is I need to rewrite or reupload a new JSON file to S3?

Comment: Basically yes. You can trigger a lambda function when any item in the table is modified. In the lambda function, you can organize the data into a JSON and upload to S3.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much. I am still new to AWS.  Maybe I will post my answer here if I have any further find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach the lambda function attached to Dynamodb using Dynamodb streams.

- When you do CURD operations on Dynamodb, it will send the event to lambda. So that we can manipulate that record in JSON file and re-upload it to S3.
- It will return the new Object and old Objects in the event.
- It will give the Keys which are modified in the records.

Answer (score 3):

Yes S3 objects are immutable, no edits once the object is created. Enabling versioning to be considered, and life cycle of your old versions of the file.